# How do I draw multiple rectangles into a canvas at once?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm drawing a large number (~20000) of rectangles to a HTML5 canvas using drawRect, each at a different, predetermined position. I'm doing this from a loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 200; ++j) {
        context.fillStyle = '#000000';
        context.fillRect(i * 8, j * 2, 6, 1);
    }
}
```

[Working demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/er22eyuf/)

This snippet draws 100 bars into a 800px wide canvas, each of them 6px wide, and each of them consisting of numerous small (1x6) rectangles stacked below each other: a static count of 200 of them in the provided example, but a dynamically changing count in my application (hence the need for rerendering them).

This takes a few tens of milliseconds, nothing serious by itself. But this entire process is invoked repeatedly, which affects performance *significantly*, and not in the good way.

**Is there a solution or workaround to make, say, such a bar be drawn in one canvas instruction, hopefully exploiting hardware acceleration much better?**

The rectangles each receive a glow in my app, so slicing through them horizontally is not a good approach. I already tried using an offscreen canvas, drawing there, and rendering it's image output to the main canvas, but there's no noticable performance gain.

Comment: Did you try keeping the offscreen canvas around for the next iteration? If the content is "static", why do you keep redrawing it?

Comment: @Amit The bar heights change depending on input data, hence the need for rerendering. I think I'll edit this into the question.

Comment: OK... so can you at least copy 1 of the bars to the rest? (possibly in a "binary incremental" 1 - 2 - 4 - 8... fashion?)

Comment: @Amit It's possible in theory, but seem very infeasible in practice. The input data using which the bars are drawn is a byte frequency data originating from a [Web Audio API Analyser node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode).

Comment: Opposite approach: Have the full bars in a static image / offscreen canvas, copy that to the target canvas, then `ctx.clearRect` the area you don't need. Would that be ok?

Comment: JSFiddle demo – mah eyes! Maybe you can use pattern fill instead of rectangle drawing?

Comment: See http://mdn.github.io/voice-change-o-matic/

Comment: @Amit Yes, in fact, that's what I was thinking about. Although that will require a separate pass for creating the glow effect, as the gradient would be cut as well.

Comment: Depending on the exact effect you're creating, you should be able to clear a little more then you really need and only fill back the last rect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make yourself a single (offscreen) canvas image containing a single full-height bar, and then for each dynamic height bar only copy the required number of vertical pixels from that onto the onscreen canvas.

Comment: @John White. Alnitak has your answer here. It's much faster to copy an image than to draw new rectangles. You can use the clipping version of `drawImage` to copy only your desired number of vertical rectangles from the source bar to the on-screen canvas. BTW, I know your example code is just for demo, but move `context.fillStyle='#000000'
` out of your loop -- it just needs to be set once before the loop begins. And replacing `for` loops with `while` loops would make your demo faster also.

Comment: @markE Yes, this is kind of what I was thinking I should have done, although I thought there was something trivial I was missing.

Comment: @JohnWhite. I couldn't resist doing a timing test between the additive and subtractive methods: https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/0vjz3dqh/. Using either method, I got performance of about 1ms per screen of bars on my modestly fast computer.

Comment: @MarkE on my laptop I'm getting ~0.15 ms for the one bar method, and 0.45 ms for the other.

Comment: @Alnitak, sounds like a nice laptop...I'm jealous!

Comment: @MarkE Early 2015 13" rMBP dual core 3.1 GHz i7 with (relatively crappy) integrated graphics

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize useful variables like this:

```
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var map = context.getImageData(startX, startY, width, height);
```

where canvas is the return value for something like `document.getElementById("myCanvas")`.

`startX` is the start x, `startY` is the start y. You can use 0 as values for them, but I prefer to not assume that this starts at the left-top point of the canvas. `width` is the width and `height` is the height. Now, you can have your loop and set values, like this:

```
map.data[4 * index] = r; //red
map.data[4 * index + 1] = g; //green
map.data[4 * index + 2] = b; // blue
```

when you are done with your loop, save things, like this:

```
context.putImageData(map, startX, startY);
```

The speed should be improved, since you are reading only once and drawing only once. As about the loops, you are just setting values, which is a cheap operation compared to drawing into the canvas. So, the idea of this optimization is, to: read things at once, set the values in a loop and draw only once instead of drawing each time you get some input. You can also omit reading the relevant parts and generate the data yourself, but I decided to show you how you can read data if you need to know something about the already drawn things.

Comment: That would mean everything has to be done "by hand". There's a lot of power in the Context2D object, with all the stroking, filling, effect and so on.

Comment: @Amit, not really. My answer is not about needing to do it by hand. It is about avoiding repeated drawing. My solution proposal is "doing it by hand", because I have not worked enough with canvases to know its functionalities by heart. You can do it like my suggestion or you can use some functions from somewhere. While I am not hiding the importance of the method you are solving the problem with, I emphasize that the most important is the idea here: namely, that one should reduce the number of drawings to optimize.

Comment: @LajosArpad. I suspect this method would be quite a bit slower because it changes individual pixels rather than groups of pixels and because `getImageData` & `putImageData` are not hardware optimized.

Comment: @markE, this method loads image data from the canvas, parses it and then stores it. Your statement about individual pixel change would be valid if this method was storing each pixel separately. Instead, it prepares all the pixels and then stores the prepared values at once. So, I disagree with your first statement.

Comment: @markE, as about your second statement about hardware optimization, I am sure that the question is at least a bit more complicated, since there are many browsers accross many operating systems. Unless your statement is true for each and every browser (that these functions are not hardware-optimized), then you have a great point. However, is there an alternative, some functions which do the same tasks and are hardware optimized in all successful browsers?

Comment: @LajosArpad. The last time I researched (a little more than a year ago)  `getImageData & putImageData` were not GPU optimized on any commonly used browser. For mono-chromatic pixel manipulation, it's common to create a mask of pixels you want to change and then use compositing to apply that mask to the original image. But masking is not very useful here. Cheers!

Comment: @LajosArpad. If you hypothesize that `putImageData` will be faster than the additive (drawImage) or subtractive (clearRect) methods, then I'm always willing to learn a faster technique. :-) Here's a perf-model of the additive & subtractive methods for you to add your putImageData algorithm to: https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/0vjz3dqh/

Comment: @markE, interesting thoughts. Maybe I should be using drawImage instead of putImageData.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that this looks some kind of background over which you are going to draw something else, have you considered converting this into a static image and setting the canvas background to this? You could turn off / on the background or whatever you draw on the canvas is going to overlap the background in the areas where the fill / draw happens.

Of, if you are going to adjust this dynamically, a separate canvas element positioned exactly under another one would also be something to consider.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but the bar heights change depending on input data, that's why it is necessary to rerender. I forgot to include this in my question.

Comment: Ah ok! I'd mistakenly assumed that it was a background. Would all the bars heights / widths be the same for one set of input data? By the way, you can move the fillStyle out of the loop for some `minor` performance gain (if that's not going to change)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. In fact, it's to be an audio visualizer component sometime soon, so for the same value on a frequency, the _same number_ of these small rectangles are to be drawn.